# ImageView covering other contents in android

Tags: java, android

The image is covering the textView and buttons(I cant even see them at all so I'm guessing they are behind the image). Image is attached. I want the textview and buttons to appear below the imageview. Below is my xml file.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>


<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    >
<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/imageView9"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:scaleType="fitStart"
    android:src="@drawable/bw" />
<EditText
    android:id="@+id/name"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_below="@+id/imageView1"
     />

<Button
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="New Button"
    android:id="@+id/button" />

<Button
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="New Button"
    android:id="@+id/button2" />

</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can change the main layout to `RelativeLayout`, set the `ImageView` at the top 
and wrap the views below the `ImageView`, inside a separate layout.  
By setting `android:layout_above="@+id/linear"` for the `ImageView`, you will be sure that the `ImageView` will never cover the other views.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView9"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_above="@+id/linear"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:scaleType="fitStart"
        android:src="@drawable/bw" />

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/linear"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:gravity="center_horizontal">

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/name"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/button"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="New Button" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/button2"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="New Button" />
    </LinearLayout>
</RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try changing the parent layout to a RelativeView, or a ConstraintView. If you don't want to redo your positioning of your layout, you can wrap everything except the Image in a LinearLayout.

```
<RelativeView>
   <ImageView>
   <LinearLayout>
     //...All your stuff
   </LinearLayout>
<RelativeView>
```

This isn't one way of course, try to experiment. Feel free to ask if you still encounter problems.